# How to get the max available bars in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to I get the max available bars for an asset?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot know on beforehand how many bars there are in a dataset.
The only way to know that, is to show the `bar_index` on the last bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(bar_index))
```